# How to SELECT column which field name contains a dot

Tags: sql, ado

I am using ADO to import data from Excel workbooks. I'm having some troubles with one worksheets where one column name contains a dot : "Col.1".

I tried everything I found : double quotes, brackets, backstick. Nothing works. Either an error is raised or the query output "Col.1" on every row.

```
QUERY_SQL = _
"SELECT `Col.1`, Col3 FROM [table$] " & _
"IN '" & SourcePath & "' " & CHAINE_HDR
```

Given the fact that I can't rename the column in the source file,

**How can I manually select this column using its name not its number ([F1]) ?**

Comment: Do you mean you've tried square brackets `[]` or parenthesis `()`?

Comment: what about escaping the dot with a backslash? `\.`

Comment: have you tried writing the dot symbol as something like the html escaping or using a *'* before the *.*?

Comment: can you change column name in excel?

Comment: @DannyStaple I'v tried brackets.
I'm gonna try to escape the dot with backslash, don't know if VBA can handle this.
As said in the post, I cannot change the column name.

Comment: Escape the dot with backslash don't generate error about synthax but about the query. It says it is empty. I guess it doesn't recognize this column.

Comment: how you name an excel column? arent they all just letters?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I finally found how to retrieve data from this column.

You need to **replace "." by "#"** and put the column name in square brackets or backsticks :

```
QUERY_SQL = _
"SELECT `Col#1`, Col3 FROM [table$] " & _
"IN '" & SourcePath & "' " & CHAINE_HDR
```

**However this will not work in INSERT INTO queries.** :

```
INSERT INTO [sheet$] (Col2, `Col#4`) IN '" & TargetPath & "' 'Excel 12.0;' " & QUERY_SQL
```

While this is less problematic for me as I can rename all field in the target sheets, this is still a strange behaviour.

Comment: The # and backticks didn't work for me, but enclosing column name in backtick quotes did work.  I'm connecting to SQLite via R.  Thanks so much for this answer.

```> dbGetQuery(conn, "SELECT  userid FROM tlogs_raw LIMIT 1")
Error: no such column: userid
> dbGetQuery(conn, "SELECT  user.id FROM tlogs_raw LIMIT 1")
Error: no such column: user.id
> dbGetQuery(conn, "SELECT  `user#id` FROM tlogs_raw LIMIT 1")
Error: no such column: user#id
> dbGetQuery(conn, "SELECT  `user.id` FROM tlogs_raw LIMIT 1")
   User.ID
1 94125108```