# how to use space and dots in fieldname vba excel sQL?

Tags: sql, excel, vba

In Excel, I am executing a VBA SQL Statement to get data from w sheet.
Everything is working when the column selected does not hold any blanks.

--Update --: it seems to be the decimal points.
And this led me to the answer: replace dots with #.

### [How to SELECT column which field name contains a dot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43784289/how-to-select-column-which-field-name-contains-a-dot)

e.g. 
    sqlSelect = " select [PRIOS$].`Development` from [PRIOS$]"

however, if it does, I can't figure out how to make it work:

sqlSelect = " select [PRIOS$].`PROD 24.04.2020` from [PRIOS$]" --> this throws runtime error (automation error) 80004005.

Unfortunately I missed actually adding the information that both the backticks and the brackets don't work.

Using brackets:

```
sqlSelect = " select [PRIOS$].[PROD 24.04.2020] from [PRIOS$]"
```

or using backticks:

```
sqlSelect = " select [PRIOS$].`PROD 24.04.2020` from [PRIOS$]"
```

both throws automation error: 'unkown failure'.

Renaming the column to something else without spaces, makes it work.

The answers I find online all point to one of the two solutions, both options unfortunately do not seem to work. Strange..

Many thanks

Comment: You have not said what you have tried, but have you put square brackets around the field - `[PROD 24.04.2020]`?

Comment: Use square brackets or backticks for columns with spaces or special characters.

Comment: sorry for leaving out that important detail - I had tried both options; I have now added that information in. Update - it seems to be the decimal points, if I leave these out, it works with the backticks.

Comment: found it - need to replace the dots by #

Answer (score 0):

it was not the spaces but the dots, which caused the problem. 
And that question had already been answered so this is a duplicate :)
voted to close my own question :)
The solution is using #