# Copy selective columns from one sheet to another using ADO VBA

Tags: excel, vba, office365, ado

I have a `Summary data` sheet containing the 1st row with selective column names, that i want to fill with data pulled from `Paste data` sheet using ADO. I have written the following code:

```
Sub CreateSummaryData()
Dim oCon As Object, oRec As Object
Dim strSQL As String
Dim wb As Workbook, wk1 As Worksheet, wk2 As Worksheet
Dim xLastColumn As Long, xLastRow As Long, i As Integer
Dim xCell, xRng As Range

On Error Resume Next
Set wb = ThisWorkbook

Set wk1 = wb.Worksheets("Paste Data")
Set wk2 = wb.Worksheets("Summary of data")

Set oCon = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set oRec = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

With oCon
    .Open Join$(Array("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source='" & _
    wb.FullName & "';Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0; HDR=YES;IMEX=0"""), vbNullString)
End With

With wk2
    xLastColumn = .Range("1:1").Cells(.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    If xLastColumn = 1 Then Exit Sub
    
    Set xRng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, xLastColumn))
    
    strSQL = ""
    strSQL = "SELECT "
    For Each xCell In xRng
        strSQL = strSQL & "[" & xCell.Value2 & "],"
    Next xCell
    strSQL = Left(strSQL, Len(strSQL) - 1)
    strSQL = strSQL & " FROM [" & wk1.Name & "$]"
End With

With oRec
    .Open strSQL, oCon, 3, 3
End With

wk2.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset oRec

With oCon
    .Close
End With

Set oRec = Nothing
Set oCon = Nothing

End Sub
```

The problem is that the `Paste Data` sheet columns contain spaces or dots in between their names. I think this is the reason why the ADO recordset shows up as empty with "operation is not allowed when object is closed" error.

The column names are like this:

```
+-----------+---------+---------+------+------------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| segmentId | segment | concept | type | metric.base.size | p.5 | p.4 | p.3 | p.2 | p.1 | fitted.p.5 | fitted.p.4 | fitted.p.3 | fitted.p.2 | fitted.p.1 | Mean Value |
+-----------+---------+---------+------+------------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

I have tried encapsulating the column names using "[" or "`", but wasn't very helpful. Is there a way to handle this issue in ADO itself without resorting to manipulating the column names in `Paste data` or `Summary of data` sheets?

Any help would be most appreciated.

**Edit**:

After commenting `On error resume next`, I get the following error on the break line i.e. when it encounters the first columnname with "." in it viz., `metric.base.size`:

[image]

I also tried the solution given in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43784289/how-to-select-column-which-field-name-contains-a-dot) but got the following error:
[image]

Here is the complete column names that i formatted after following the above post. I also tried enclosing with "[" brackets as well as "`", but got same error. Is it because there are more than one "." or " " in a column?

```
SELECT `segmentId`,`exerciseConceptId`,`ConceptName`,`ConceptType`,`Groups`,`Segment`,`metric#base#size`,`fitted#p#5`,`fitted#p#4`,`fitted#p#3`,`fitted#p#2`,`fitted#p#1`,`MeanFrequency`,`MeanUnitsFav`,`MeanValue` FROM [Paste Data$]
```

Comment: Comment out the `On Error Resume Next` and run your code.  Do you get any error, and what error on which line?

Comment: Hi @TimWilliams. long time no see. I have edited my above post to include further findings. Still erroring out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me - replace any period in a field name with `#`

```vb
For Each xCell In xRng
    strSQL = strSQL & "[" & Replace(xCell.Value2, ".", "#") & "],"
Next xCell
```

This is the solution from your linked post - you don't show all your code for that so I'm not sure why it didn't work for you.

Comment: Tim what is the full code you are using? I already tried that. Maybe I am missing something. BTW, are you replacing the fieldnames in Paste Data sheet or Summary of Data sheet? Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: The only change I made from the code you posted was the line  `strSQL = strSQL & "[" & Replace(xCell.Value2, ".", "#") & "],"`   Everything else is the same.   I'm not changing the headers on either worksheet - only the SQL string is affected.  So (for example) a field with header "A.B" needs to be "A#B" in the SQL.

Comment: I will share my workbook if you need it.

Comment: Sure. Thanks. The original code is the one i posted. But later, i was doing trial and error by adding additional lines to original code to replace the characters. So didn't choose to show it as i thought it was understandable.

Comment: My file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Tb-lgz22pH3HsA5_lC42jsTMJaDi6s8S/view?usp=sharing

Comment: getting error `Cannot update. Database or error read-only." on `        .Open Join$(Array("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source='" & _
        wb.FullName & "';Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0; HDR=YES;IMEX=0"""), vbNullString)` as i think because `wb.FullName` gives me an `https://xxx.my-sharepoint.com/xxx/xxx` link..I am on MS Excel 365 with onedrive/sharepoint....another bummer to translate this back to local system... :(

Comment: Yes it won't work on with a http path.

Comment: FWIW, Tim's answer works for me, on a locally saved workbook. The answer I posted would only have ended up with field names, enclosed in quotes, copied down - something I suspected after posting but only got the chance to confirm now.